# SQL mathematical function regross amount

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Server 2005, I want to regross back the net amount which is

```
Gross Amount (RM 150)
After 10% discount is 
CHECKS.Payment (RM135)

     ELSE (+'"') + CONVERT(varchar(25), (CHECKS.Payment/90%)) + '"'
  END AS [Gross Transaction Amount],
```

I got an error with this code.

Seeking for expertise help.

Comment: This almost looks like one of those Perl poems.  Where is the rest of your query?

Comment: Also - please, if you *tease* us with *I got an error* - tell us ***WHAT ERROR*** that is - give us the complete and precise error message so that we know what you're talking about. Remember: we can't see your screen, nor read your mind! (yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your requirements, you're trying to take a payment field in your checks table and reverse a 10% discount?

If so, you can't use `payment/90%` (`%` is a `mod` operator).  Instead use `payment/.9`:

```
select payment/.9 discountedpayment  from checks
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f05c/2)

BTW -- if your payment field in your checks table isn't a decimal, you may need to cast accordingly depending on your desired output.

Comment: He needs to divide by 0.9, not multiply, to get back to the gross amount.  You get an upvote for herculean translation efforts, however.

Comment: SELECT CASE
    WHEN CHECKS.SubTotal < 0 THEN (+'"') + CONVERT(varchar(20), CHECKS.SubTotal) + '"'
    ELSE (+'"') + CONVERT(varchar(25), (CHECKS.Payment/0.9)) + '"'
  END AS ["Gross Transaction Amount"],